# How to create a new column in pyspark?

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

In my pyspark DataFrame I have two columns `price1` and `price2`. I want to create a new column `result` based on the formula `((price1 - price2)/price1)`. However, I want also to check that neither `price1` nor `price2` are null, and `price1` is not `0`.

How can I correctly create a new column using these conditions?

Now I have this:

```
df = df.withColumn("result", df["price1"]-df["price2"]/df["price1"])
```

Comment: what result do you expect if `price1==0` or if one prices is `null`?

Comment: @MaxU: Sorry, I have not specified it. If `price1==0` or any price is equal to `null`, then I expect `result` to be equal to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it this way:

```
df = df.withColumn("result", df["price1"]-df["price1"]/df["price2"]).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use udf,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

udf = F.udf(lambda x,y : 0 if x == 0 or not all((x,y)) else x-y/x)
df = df.withColumn("result", udf(df["price1"],df["price2"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.withColumn("result", 
when(df.col("price1").isNull OR df.col("price2").isNull OR df.col("price1")==0,0)
.otherwise(df.col("price1")-df.col("price2")/df.col("price1")))
```

This is how it can be done using scala..